# Get-ADuser to list invalid user from list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using a Powershell script in an installation environment to check that a list of AD users has been properly added and setup by the customer.

I've got the script working, and it outputs what I need for accounts that do exist in AD from the `user.txt` file.  I also need it to list the accounts that show up as invalid/not created, but cannot figure it out.  Any suggestions?

```
$Users = gc "C:\scripts\Users.txt" 
Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,Enabled,MemberOf,PasswordNeverExpires,LockedOut |
? { $Users -contains $_.SamAccountName } | 
select DisplayName, SamAccountName, Enabled, MemberOf, PasswordNeverExpires, LockedOut | 
Out-File c:\scripts\results\UserResults.txt
```

Comment: If by "any suggestions" you mean "can someone rewrite this for me so it works the way I expect", then no. If you really want a suggestion, then you can use `Get-ADUse`'s `-LDAPFilter` parameter with a filter such as `(sAMAccountName=<whatever>)` to check whether a user exists. If this command's output is `$null`, then the user doesn't exist.

Comment: Any errors from your code? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already pulling every user with `-Filter *`, you could use `Compare-Object` to then see which items in the text file are not `SamAccountNames`

```
$Users = gc "C:\scripts\Users.txt" 
$ADusers = Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,Enabled,MemberOf,PasswordNeverExpires,LockedOut |
    select DisplayName, SamAccountName, Enabled, MemberOf, PasswordNeverExpires, LockedOut 

$ADusers |
    ? { $Users -contains $_.SamAccountName } |
    Out-File c:\scripts\results\UserResults.txt

Compare-Object $ADusers.SamAccountName $users | 
    ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq =>} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject |
    Out-File c:\scripts\results\Failures.txt
```